# RazorEngine trying to update model for email template

Tags: c#, razor

I am trying to use the RazorEngine for email templates (http://razorengine.codeplex.com/)

I have got this working but I want to store the subject inside the template as well.  What is the best way to update the model inside the template I have tried just using `@(Model.Subject="xyz")` and this does work but also outputs the string in the parsed template.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you considered a comment? (`<!-- Subject: Subject here -->`)

Comment: Aside from the issue, why are you changing the model data in the view?

Comment: Well this is using razor for templates not inside a web application.  If the template can return information it helps with localization.  In this case the email subject.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's for email templates. The MVC principle still applies. The calling code should set up the model, the template should present the data however it wants to without changing that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured this out use braces around the code section to execute, makes sense really.

So instead of using

```
@(Model.Subject="xyz")
```

Use

```
@{Model.Subject="xyz";}
```